# List data will only draw the list names, not the actual data in the list

Tags: python, list, random, drawing

I want my list data to be read as its data entries rather than the position it is in the data.

For example
['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
Should be read as it says

But instead it reads the data as
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

How do I make it say the suitenumbers instead.

Ive played around with it for a fair bit trying to rename the data to produce something different but I dont really know what Im doing here.

```
suitenumbers = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
numcards_stack6 = randint(1, 9)

for suitenumbers in range(numcards_stack6):
      pencolor('black')
      write(suitenumbers, font=("Arial", 20, 'normal', 'bold'))
      forward(50)
```

It should draw back 
A
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function range(x) creates an item with numbers between 0 and the number you defined: 
example: 
If numcards_stack6 is 4, then range(4) iterates over [0,1,2,3]. So whenever you are going to print the variable you iterate in a range, it will always print the number of the iteration you are in, so you need to use `suitenumbers[iter]`

Also, when you use a for, you iterate a new variable over the thing you want to iterate. What you are doing is rewriting the suitenumbers variable which is wrong.

```
for iter in range(numcards_stack6):
      pencolor('black')
      write(suitenumbers[iter], font=("Arial", 20, 'normal', 'bold'))
      forward(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Randint imported from random gives you only one single number that it is why it proably prints 1 number

```
suitenumbers = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
numcards_stack6 = randint(1, 9)

for suitenumbers in range(len(suitenumbers)-3):
      pencolor('black')
      write(suitenumbers, font=("Arial", 20, 'normal', 'bold'))
      forward(50)
```

len gets the numbers of values in a list or string

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```py
for suitenumbers in range(numcards_stack6):
```

you overwrite the `suitenumbers` variable, setting it to numbers in the range as you loop through it. You should assign the number to another variable, e.g. `i` and use it to index into your `suitenumbers` list:

```py
for i in range(numcards_stack6):
      pencolor('black')
      write(suitenumbers[i], font=("Arial", 20, 'normal', 'bold'))
      forward(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using multiple possible solutions all wrong. You can either (1) loop through a loop like you did where iterable is representing index or (2) use slice notation to limit your whole list:

*1st solution:*

```
for i in range(numcards_stack6): #notice that I changed variable to i from suitenumbers, since you're using suitenumbers as name of list
    pencolor('black')
    write(suitenumbers[i], font=("Arial", 20, 'normal', 'bold'))
```

*2nd solution:*

```
for number in suitenumbers[:numcards_stack6]:
    pencolor('black')
    write(number, font=("Arial", 20, 'normal', 'bold'))
```